# Is there a way to grab the current value of the editor in Gutenburg/Classic Wordpress editor? (Not the saved value of the post!)

Tags: block-editor, tinymce, content

I'm trying to make my plugin "Gutenburg - compatible". I have some issues when replacing the editors contents. Before I could just change value by using #content but with Gutenburg there's obviously a new approach with REST API.

Is there a way to grab the current value of the editor? (***Not the saved value of the post!***)

I want this because I want to replace values of the core/editor in realtime. It works with the classic editor active but I don't want to require that.

```
let old_content = '';
old_content = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPost().content;     
//TINYMCE => old_content = $('textarea#content').html();

//Aim is to do a replace like this (and this works but only FIRST time because old_content 
//fetches from server/db instead of the actual editor (If I understand this correctly)

wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).resetBlocks( wp.blocks.parse( new_content ) );
//TINYMCE: $('textarea#content').html( new_content );
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles upon same issue I found a way to achieve what I wanted (I hope someone is helped by this).

**This is my solution:** `getEditedPostContent()` contains the temporary post (modified) content:

```
let old_content = '';
if ($('textarea#content').length >0) {
  old_content = $('textarea#content').html();
}
else {
  //"Gutenburg" style (>=WP 5.8)
  old_content = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPost().content; 
  if ( wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostContent() ) {
    old_content =  wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostContent();
  } 
}
```

And the actual replacement:

```
if ($('textarea#content').length >0) {
   $('textarea#content').html( new_content );
}
else {
  //"Gutenburg" style (>=WP 5.8)
  wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).resetBlocks( wp.blocks.parse( new_content ) );
}
```